# caption outside float in figure Beamer/Latex

Tags: latex, caption, beamer

I am trying to add a photo that actually works in the `main.tex` until I insert one of the captions. Is there any way to get around this? many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=blue}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{DNA - Computing}
\author{A}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
%6 FOTO
\begin{frame}{DNA (1)}
    \begin{itemize}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.50\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=4cm]{./6.jpg}
            %\caption{Aufbau DNA}
            %\captionof{./6.jpg}{Abbildung: Aufbau DNA}%
            
            \column{0.50\linewidth}     
            \item Desoxyribonukleinsäure
            \pause \item Speicherung der Erbinformationen/ Multiprozessorsysteme
            \pause \item Doppelhelix 
            \pause \item Grundbausteinen:   
            \begin{itemize}
                \item kleiner organische Basen
                \item Zuckermoleküle
                \item Phosphatgruppen  
            \end{itemize} 
        \end{columns} 
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- you can't use `\caption` outside of a `figure` (or `table`) environment
- You have to specify the float type in `\captionof`, not the file name, e.g. `\captionof{figure}{Aufbau DNA}` to set the caption of a figure

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=blue}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{DNA - Computing}
\author{A}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
%6 FOTO
\begin{frame}{DNA (1)}
    \begin{itemize}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.50\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=4cm]{example-image-duck}
%            \caption{Aufbau DNA}
            \captionof{figure}{Aufbau DNA}%
            
            \column{0.50\linewidth}     
            \item Desoxyribonukleinsäure
            \pause \item Speicherung der Erbinformationen/ Multiprozessorsysteme
            \pause \item Doppelhelix 
            \pause \item Grundbausteinen:   
            \begin{itemize}
                \item kleiner organische Basen
                \item Zuckermoleküle
                \item Phosphatgruppen  
            \end{itemize} 
        \end{columns} 
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```